# How to get rid of or reduce the gap of an equation break?

Tags: equations, formatting

I am writing a long equation and I have to use the align environment to break it.

Here is the code:

```
\begin{align*} 
A_C\Delta\phi_{2\,C}^\star - \sum_{i\in\mathcal{N}}A_i\Delta\phi_{2\,i}^\star = b_{C} +& A_C^x(\phi_{1\,C}^\star - \phi_{2\,C}^\star) - \\ 
& A_W(\phi_{1\,W}^\star - \phi_{2\,W}^\star) - \\
& A_E(\phi_{1\,E}^\star - \phi_{2\,E}^\star),
\end{align*}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

The issue comes that there is a "big" jump between the first line and the second line of the previous equation due to the sum index. How to eliminate (or reduce) this gap between lines of a broken equation?

Thanks

Comment: The minus signs at the right are also too close to the preceding material.  It's better (more conventional) to place such signs of operation at the beginning of continuation lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put the `\sum` in a `\smash[b]{...}` command. I took the opportunity to propose a slightly different layout for this equation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
A_C\Delta\phi_{2\,C}^\star -\smash[b]{\sum_{i\in\mathcal{N}}}A_i\Delta\phi_{2\,i}^\star = b_{C} +{}& A_C^x(\phi_{1\,C}^\star - \phi_{2\,C}^\star) - \\
& A_W(\phi_{1\,W}^\star - \phi_{2\,W}^\star) - \\
& A_E(\phi_{1\,E}^\star - \phi_{2\,E}^\star),
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
A_C\Delta\phi_{2\,C}^\star -\smash[b]{\sum_{i\in\mathcal{N}}}A_i\Delta\phi_{2\,i}^\star = b_{C} & +A_C^x(\phi_{1\,C}^\star - \phi_{2\,C}^\star) \\
 & -A_W(\phi_{1\,W}^\star - \phi_{2\,W}^\star) \\
&- A_E(\phi_{1\,E}^\star - \phi_{2\,E}^\star),
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\smash[b]{\sum_{i\in\mathcal{N}}A_i\Delta\phi_{2\,i}^\star}` would use the correct spacing after the summation.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, I wrote   `[b]` purposely, as there might be a full line of text above the sum.

Comment: @campa: it seems I misunderstood. Anyway the larger spacing was due to the subscript being wider than the sum symbol, and my code has the same effect as the `\smashoperator` command from `mathtools`. Personally, I prefer it like that.

Comment: I does have the same effect, at least in this case, for a reason I don't understand – I used both to test, and the measured difference is less than 0.1pt.

Answer (score 2):

```
\begin{align*} 
A_C\Delta\phi_{2\,C}^\star - \sum_{i\in\mathcal{N}}A_i\Delta\phi_{2\,i}^\star = b_{C} &+ A_C^x(\phi_{1\,C}^\star - \phi_{2\,C}^\star)  \\[-.75pc] 
&- A_W(\phi_{1\,W}^\star - \phi_{2\,W}^\star)  \\
&- A_E(\phi_{1\,E}^\star - \phi_{2\,E}^\star),
\end{align*}
```

Try out this!